# Android NDK Build error in Cygwin

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin

I am configuring NDK for an android app which makes use of the linux/input.h file in its header - #include . The issue is when I call ndk-build, it gives an error which basically implies that it cannot find linux/input.h. Now, cygwin does not contain the linux directory, which is probably why this error is occuring but the ndk does contain it - android-ndk-r8e\platforms\android-14\arch-x86\usr\include\linux\input.h - shouldn't ndk-build search here as well? To give some more context, I am trying to compile the EventInjector library described [here](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2013/01/programmatically-injecting-events-on-android-part-2) and others seem to have it working, which means it must be possible somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these instructions:

1. in Android.mk

> ```
> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
> TARGET_PLATFORM := android-8
> LOCAL_MODULE    := your_lib
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := my_file.c
> LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
> include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)</li>
> ```
>
> **your_lib** will be the name of your library, you may write any name

**my_file.c** will be your source file name that is present in JNI folder

> ```
> Right click on project
> Choose Properties>Builders
> Click on New...
> Select Program, then Ok
>
> In main tab:
> Give your Builder a suitable name, eg. "NDK"
> For Location, click on Browse file system>select your ndk-build.cmd,
> eg. C:\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd (My NDK path)
>
> Below there will be Working Directory:
> Click on: Browse workspace - choose your project,
> eg. ${workspace_loc:/Test} (My project 'Test')
>
> Click on **Refresh Tab**
> Select **Specific Resources** radio button
> Click on **Specify Resources..**
> Select libs folder from your project
> Now click on **Build Options** Tab
> Check:
> After a Clean
> During manual builds
> During auto builds
> Specify working set of relevant resources 
> Click on **Specify Resources...**
> Select JNI folder of your project
> Click Apply...Ok
> ```

Now clean it and build...then refresh

You will get your_lib.so in libs>armeabi
libs>armeabi>your_lib.so this structure will create automatically ....